# Debug angular app from outside (browser console only)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

I have this angular website which for some reason cannot be debugged when everything is concat together (not minified). Fo example, if I try to set a breakpoint, the breakpoint is placed somewhere else (at the bottom of an other file) :(

So, to overcome this I would like to set a breakpoint using the browser console (if possible of course).

In my current situation I need to set a breakpoint inside a service method. So I figured, I need the reference holding that service. But where does angular keep those. For example, I tried this

```
$> var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
$> debug(myApp.injector('someSevice').someMethod);
```

If this would work, I would expect the debugger to kick in when `someMethod` is called.

Here is an other failed attempt:

```
$> myApp.run((someService) => { debug(someService.someMethod)});
```

Any help on how to do this would be appreciated?

UPDATE: Find a way to access a service

```
$> angular.injector(['myApp']).get('someService').someMethod
```

However, in my case, this function is called initially only

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to debug a live production app, there might be a chance where the `debug info` is disabled for the website which is actually done to `increase performance` of the website. So use `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();` in console and then try to debug.

Comment: If I do that I still can't place a breakpoint. I'm not sure what `reloadWithDebugInfo` does, but in the app is no debug stuff

Comment: Try placing the breakpoint at the end of the function or service.. i.e at `}` of the function, it should stop there, it generally happens when the functions are actually concatenated by `,` in a variable or any other such.

Comment: Its compiled code (ES2015 to ES5) and indeed with the `,`, but wherever I click I always endup with a breakpoint at the end of that other file

Comment: Did you try placing the breakpoint after pretty print of code? Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpkzvm9jnsu9wid/2016-09-05_16-30-07.png?dl=0)'s an part of a service in which I would like to place the breakpoint

Comment: Try inserting a breakpoint at start of a function i.e where the variable is first declared. It should help. If still it doesn't help you, better do a  hard reload of the website.

Comment: I've tried almost everything now, still with the same result. The weird thing is, that the other file (where the breakpoint always end up) does place the breakpoint where I click. Do you maybe have some url of where this issue is addressed ?